# Lagrange multipliers with two constraints.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have been working on the following problem. I need to find a minimum of the following function:

$$\ 6x-y^2+xz+60=0 $$

subject to the following constraints:

$$ z-x+y=0 \\ x^2+y^2+z^2=36 $$

I have the following equations for the Lagrange multipliers:

$$ 6+z = 2\lambda x -\mu \\
-2y = 2 \lambda y + \mu \\
z = 2\lambda z + \mu \\
x^2 + y^2+ z^2 = 36 \\
z-x+y=0$$

I have found that the system does not have solution on the reals, nor the system defined by the first three equations so there are no points to evaluate for a minimum or maximum. Am i correct? Or am I missing something. Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: I suppose that you want the minimum of  $6x+y^2+z^2+60$ and not the minimum $6x+y^2+z^2+60=0$ (otherwise, the problem is done) ! I suggest you fix the first equation in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a typo in the post and that you want the extremum of $6x+y^2+z^2+60$ subject to the given constraints.

So, just as you did, let us write the Lagrangian $$F=6 x+y^2+z^2+60+\lambda  (-x+y+z)+\mu  \left(x^2+y^2+z^2-36\right)$$ and write the partial derivatives $$F'_x=-\lambda +2 \mu  x+6$$ $$F'_y=\lambda +2 \mu  y+2 y$$ $$F'_z=\lambda +2 \mu  z+2 z$$ $$F'_\lambda= -x+y+z$$ $$F'_\mu=x^2+y^2+z^2-36$$ Using the first four partial derivatives (set equal to $0$), we then obtain (solving four linear equations for four unknowns is not too hard almost if you use matrix calculations) $$x=-\frac{6}{3 \mu +1}\quad,\quad y=-\frac{3}{3 \mu +1}\quad,\quad z=-\frac{3}{3 \mu +1}\quad,\quad \lambda=\frac{6 (\mu +1)}{3 \mu +1}$$ Plugging in $F'_\mu$, after some minor simplifications, we get $$\frac{54}{(3 \mu +1)^2}=36$$ which shows two real roots.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: i have just realized that there was a typo on my question, i have just fixed that. Sorry.